# Can't repeat same day,time from , time to when click on "add more"

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

[image]

If i Click on "add more" button then one row generate with Day , Time from , Time to etc. If i again Click and Select Same day Then can't repeat Time from and time to previously selected.

Comment: should not add duplicate data is it ?

Comment: Clone the object, reset the selection or values using DOM traverse methods and append them

Comment: Yes ,not allowed duplication if same day select otherwise allow @JYoThI